# jxls-poi 2.12.0 / JEXLS - Can't get custom functions in expression not resolved

Tags: jxls, jexl

Using jxls, I'm trying to use use a custom processing function in a template with the following code :

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.createTransformer(template, outputStream);
JexlExpressionEvaluator evaluator = (JexlExpressionEvaluator) transformer.getTransformationConfig().getExpressionEvaluator();

Map<String, Object> functions = new HashMap<>();
functions.put("functions", new XlsExportUtils());

JexlEngine customJexlEngine = new JexlBuilder().namespaces(functions).create();
evaluator.setJexlEngine(customJexlEngine);
JxlsHelper.getInstance().processTemplate(context, transformer);
```

My method in the XlsExportUtils class is a simple testing method :

```
public String test() {
    return "toto";
}
```

And I'm trying several ways to call it in the template but none of them seem to work :

A dot notation :
${functions.test()}

Or a colon ":" notation as seen in another example on the internet :

```
${functions:test()}
```

Both returns :

```
unsolvable function/method 'test'
```

Same for a method taking an argument. In this case, the lib tries to resolve the type of argument depending on the expression.

For example, if I hardcode an int argument like : test(1), I get the error

```
unsolvable function/method 'test(Short)'
```

If I hardcode a bigger value, the argument in the error message changes to "Long"

If I pass a variable corresponding to an Integer :
Ex:
${functions:test(myObject.myInt)}

It wierdly resolves the argument into a Float, returning the error message :

```
 unsolvable function/method 'test(Float)'
```

Version : 2.12.0

Comment: Your code seems close to this (working) example: https://github.com/jxlsteam/jxls/blob/2.12.0-release/jxls-poi/src/test/java/org/jxls/examples/JexlCustomFunctionDemo.java.

The problem must be in the detail as in: is your XlsExportUtils class public (static) with a default constructor ? Is the method you try to call public ? Could you share the actual code as a unit test ?

Comment: Sorry, I had to use a workaround that doesn't involve the library as I spent too much time rying to make it work. The only thing different from what you've listed is the default constructor. I'll try adding the constructor as soon as I find some time to fiddle around with this again. 
Thanks.